# Conduit sizing for three #10 THHN wires

Tags: wiring

Is 1/2" PVC conduit sized properly for three #10 THHN wires ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Is this conduit schedule 40 or schedule 80?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's legal.

If it's a particularly complex pull, larger pipe size can help.  It can also help with the fact that you can easily put 4 circuits in a conduit (if it meets the fill rules).

Now, since you mentioned this is a dryer and you are running hot/neutral/ground... If it's a gas dryer you are on the right track.

If it's an electric dryer, we must deep-dive into the arcana of dangerous and obsolete dryer connections.  Old 3-prong dryers used no ground, and worse, they attached the chassis of the dryer to neutral.  This has the potential of being dangerous in several ways.  As such they have been outlawed for 30 years.   And even when they were legal, it was NEVER legal to use /2+gnd (black white bare) to connect them - though it was done shamefully often.

Since you are doing a new cable run, you MUST bring it up to current Code.  This isn't far out of your way; you just need to use 4 wires in the conduit instead of 3.  The 2 hot wires can be the same color - but neutral must be white, and ground must be green or bare.

I for one recommend using stranded wire, because it's a lot easier to pull.

By the way,  if you use EMT metal conduit, the conduit is the ground - one less wire.

And yes, you will need to convert the dryer socket and cord to NEMA 14-30.

Comment: Did you mean 4 conductors? There is no limit to the number of “circuits” except by wire fill volume.

Comment: @EdBeal Nope, 4 circuits max because OP is using #10 for a typically 22A load.  If OP went to 5 circuits, the #10 wire would only be good to 20A, and could not support the load.

Comment: Can the neutral and ground be taped white and green?

Comment: @JACK not at #10. At #6 and larger (smaller gauge numbers) (I believe that's the size it starts at) you can do that, but #8 and #10 you have to use the correct colored wire (white or gray for neutral, green or bare for ground) for them.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote.

Comment: @Ed forgot to say I am referring to the 310.15B3a derate. Note that I am presuming 120/240V split-phase,  so either each circuit is 2 wires, or if it is 3, the neutral does not count for 310.15b3a derate. So all circuits are 2 wires, at 8 wires you are at 30% derate, at 10 wires you are at 50% derate off the 90C column (for THHN).  Which is 40A for #10.

Comment: And wrong again the max fill for 1/2” is 4 #10 thhn conductors as jack said but you can keep showing how a internet only electricians thinks. Note I backed @jack answer with the code reference.

Comment: @EdBeal I never claimed 1/2” conduit, my statement was part of a nudge to get OP to consider larger conduit.  Why are you being so over-critical these days?  You say lots of misinterpretable stuff too, difference is, *I **don't** swerve out of my way to misinterpret it*. Do you really want to live in a world where I do? Coz it seems like you are trying to "start something".

Comment: That’s what the op said he wanted to use and there is no reason to go larger.     You did not specify a change in conduit size.

Comment: @Ed did you **even read** my 2nd paragraph?  Go read it, and you’ll understand why I think you are twitting me.

Comment: After the edit, just like the past 2 questions you asked that I was the first to answer and provide code references? You did not provide a check , keep on trying I am a professional not a internet only I answer questions not much later with canned answers or all the existing answers added up a day later, just got to call them as I see them! I have only asked a few questions and even gave a up vote after the fact that I let a bonus go because no one did answer but you change the question and fail to award a check. If others look up to you they need to know the truth!

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks for making clear how you feel.  I don't generally write answers to *compete* with your answers, only to write supplemental information that might be of interest. If that bothers you, I'll just nudge you to improve your answer. Since you claim to be a pro, you'll know what's needed.  In a recent question of mine that you answered, I didn't like your answer at all, hence no + or check.

Comment: Well I can probably show you several hundred , as well as jack , ecrnewal, And Isherwood to name a few that have provided Good answers that you later take all the info and answer. three phase always asks for photos. There are also a few others , have you noticed I usually add comments backing a simple answer, because that is what most need , apprentices included ! After your last 2 BS questions I was finally done !  Are You A Bot? Just wondering, don’t care if I get bounced, I answer questions don’t edit them for my rep!

Answer (score 1):

You can pull up to 4 #10's in 1/2" conduit.  If you give us some more info we might be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks... I'm eliminating the existing 30A aluminum wire to the dryer in the garage, about 8 feet from the panel. I picked up 1/2" pvc and a few sweeps, #10 THHN black, neutral and ground. The existing dryer cord is a 3 prong which Id like to keep or should i pull another hot and spend on a new cord and receptacle? Thanks for the wisdom

Comment: Table c.10 in annex c would be the code ref please pull both hot’s neutral and a ground to be code compliant. No more than 4 90 degree turns between pull points.

Comment: Those three prong plugs are considered  dangerous, there's no ground. If your redoing the feed, run the four wires and install a NEMA 14-30 outlet and get a 4 prong plug and cord.

Comment: You will have to change the wiring inside your dryer for a 4-prong cord, but that's typically laid out on the back of the dryer itself - if not, look it up for your model of dryer. There will be a jumper that is connecting the case to neutral now, and it will (typically) move to a "storage" position when you make a 4 wire connection with a ground wire as well as the neutral wire.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I figured the OP would ask about that sooner or later, you saved him the effort.